# Preventing a cell in a Jupyter notebook from saving to disk

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Jupyter Python notebook where one particular cell has very large visual output (multiple megabytes of Javascript including embedded data).  Is there a way to mark the cell so that the output isn't saved to the `.ipynb` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this without installing a Jupyter extension. I think this can be done on the front end by, for example, creating a widget extension with a template for the JS code, then populating the template as your output, since widget state is selectively saved.

If you want a reasonable solution with a minimal amount of work and you have access to modifying the Jupyter server environment, I'd suggest using the [file save hook](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/savehooks.html) in `jupyter_notebook_config.py`. There's already an example in the documentation for stripping output. I've modified it (but not tested it!) to delete the JS output of cells tagged `no-save`.

```
def scrub_output_pre_save(model, **kwargs):
    """scrub output before saving notebooks"""
    # only run on notebooks
    if model['type'] != 'notebook':
        return
    # only run on nbformat v4
    if model['content']['nbformat'] != 4:
        return

    for cell in model['content']['cells']:
        if cell['cell_type'] != 'code':
            continue
        metadata = cell['metadata']
        if 'tags' in metadata and 'no-save' in metadata['tags']:
            cell['outputs'] = []
            cell['execution_count'] = None


 c.FileContentsManager.pre_save_hook = scrub_output_pre_save
```

If you need this to be installable/reusable the above code can be packaged and distributed as a [Jupyter server extension](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Distributing%20Jupyter%20Extensions%20as%20Python%20Packages.html).